# `atq` lists a job even if it was executed yesterday

Tags: at

I created an `at` job that executes a script with the `-f` flag. The script restarts tomcat. The job was scheduled to be executed at `Feb 21 18:00:00 2022` which was yesterday. I just confirmed tomcat was restarted at that time. However when I execute `atq` today, I get:

```
3   Mon Feb 21 18:00:00 2022 = alexander
```

My understanding is that `atq` only lists `pending` jobs. Why is my job from yesterday being listed?

Update:

I just reviewed my script and it contains `tail` which never exits at the end. That is probably causing the job to take forever to quit. I found the output at `/var/spool/at/spool/a0000301a27604`. But the file was last modified at `2022-02-21 23:40:33.534191768`. I just found out that's where the last output to tail arrived at. How do I get the process number of the still running task?

Comment: "_But the file was last modified at 2022-02-21 23:40:33.534191768, which means, at aborted the job_" - not necessarily. It just means that the file was last written at that time. Your job could be still running (and possibly still is) but just not writing anything

Comment: @roaima you're right. I confirmed that was not the case. That was the time catalina started to writing to another log file. I have edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For the latest version of your question, "*How do I get the process number of the still running task?*"

```
pgrep atd
525

pstree -p 525
atd(525)───atd(6729)───sh(6738)───sleep(6739)
```

Or, rolling the two commands together safely

```
pgrep atd | xargs -n1 -r pstree -p
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW `pgrep` returned two `pid`s for me so chaining the commands might not work the way you did it.

Comment: @Alex thank you. I've adjusted the suggested command to handle multiple PIDs